# Outlook add-in extension point in manifest file for save and edit actions

Tags: outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi, outlook-calendar

Currently we have the on-send feature, itemSend type to capture mail sending/create meeting which we implement like this in manifest file,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/extensionpoint#events

Do we have other events types like edit, save, delete for the other calendar events?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, ItemSend is the only Event ExtensionPoint for Outlook add-ins.

If you like to suggest other events please add an idea to the [Outlook add-in UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?category_id=131778). Feature requests on UserVoice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Is the code for the itemSend feature open source?

Comment: The Outlook add-in APIs are implemented natively by the Outlook clients, which are not open source.

Comment: Does ItemSend event also work for appointments?

Comment: ItemSend does work for appointments.